# res.cookie ist not saved in the browser

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cookies, request, cross-domain

I am currently trying to set up my react application and connect it to my backend. I am using JWT to create web tokens, which I then save via cookieparser.

Server is running on: http://localhost:3000/
Client is running on: http://127.0.0.1:8080/client/public/

Now, I am trying to make a post request from the client (react) and try to store the token (cookie) in the browser but it is not working. **It constantly saves the cookie onto the localhost:3000 domain and not on the domain where the client is running**. Down below the relevant code for backend and frontend:

```js
**// This is the cors setup for Express**

app.use(cors({ origin: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080', credentials: true }))

**// This is the request router API for creating the user and the cookie (and sending it to the browser)**

router.post('/api/users', async (req, res) => {
    const user = new User(req.body)
    try {
        await user.save()
        const token = await user.generateAuthToken()
        res.cookie('auth_token', token, { httpOnly: false,                 sameSite: 'none' }) 
        res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        res.send(token)
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(400).send('Did not work')
    }
})


**// This is the request from the client with Axios:**

axios.post('http://localhost:3000/api/users', {
            name: this.state.userName,
            email: this.state.userEmail,
            password: this.state.userPassword,
        }, {
            withCredentials: true,
            credentials: 'include'
        })
        .then( (response) => {
            const data = response
            console.log(data)
        })
        .catch( () => {
            console.log('Cant access backend')
        })

        this.setState({
            userName: '',
            userEmail: '',
            userPassword: ''
        })
    }
```

**Images:**

[Setting up cors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WDM9.png)

this is the api router: 
[API Router for creating user and sending it to DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzwaa.png)

this is the client (frontend) request
[Post request to register user with axios](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOfQV.png)

Thank you very much in advance for your help :)

Comment: That is right.. cookies will be saved to `localhost` coz your server host is localhost.. Its the expected behaviour. If you are expecting it you save to your client domain.. then sorry.

Answer (score -1):

You're storing the cookie in the server. For you to store in the client. Return the cookie and store it using the static js file in the client.

```
//Returned cookie
document.cookie = "auth_token=token returned by server;
```

Comment: wat!!! @adarsh Can what u mean by `storing in the server` ? 